# Access Google Gadgets preferences from Android app

Tags: android, google-gadget, google-account, igoogle

I'm going to create an iGoogle Gadget, and an Android version as well. User data will be saved in the gadget like this (javascript):

```
var prefs = new gadgets.Prefs();
prefs.set("foo","bar");
```

In Android side, the app will login with user's Google Account. Is it possible to access user data in the gadget preferences?
If not, any other way to store user data that both Gadget and Android can access with Google Account?